# ¿Cómo agregar una clase Java a iReport?

Tags: java, ireport

Tengo un reporte que quiero llenarlo con los datos de un objeto, el problema es que no sé cómo agregar esa clase en iReport?

Veo que hay una opción en `DataSource-JavaBens set datasource`.

Pero me manda el error de `Check you classpath`, entonces no sé cómo configurar el `classpath` para que me reconozca las clases Java.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es agregar tu proyecto como **librerira**, para hacerlo al compilarlo te genera un `.jar` ese es el que puedes importar en `iReports`.

En el siguente menu **Tools**-->**Option**-->**Classpath**-->**Add JAR**, luego donde dices el `dataSe`t o `Data source` esta la opcion de `java Bean` ahi lo puedes buscar